# How to view ArcGIS Online-created web mapping application on my device?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, ios, iphone

I have an ESRI Organizational account and an iphone 4s (iOS 7.1.1).  On my phone using the ArcGIS app, I am able to see all maps created in My Groups, but I cannot see a single web mapping application.  All applications have been shared to the group that I am a member of just as the maps are.  I can see them all just fine from my desktop using ArcGIS Online.

Any ideas why they are not shown on my phone?  What am I missing? How do I view my applications on my device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ArcGIS app lets you view web maps, not web mapping applications.  Web mapping applications are composed of HTML, Javascript and CSS and are accessed from a device's web browser.

Here's an example of a web mapping application:

http://keller.maps.arcgis.com/apps/PublicInformation/index.html?appid=6061c77c5f2e4b219e9ec91f9d4acd0c

It is designed to work on any device, but only from within the web browser.  You should be able to obtain the URL of your web mapping application in the app's Item Details screen.

Hope this helps.